# How do I flatten JSON Array Elements in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

I have an input DataFrame df which is as follows (ID IS NOT 1,2,3):

```
| id    | name                                                                                  |
|-------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| a1xy  | [  {  "event": "sports",   "start": "100"},  {  "event": "lunch",  "start": "121" } ] |
| a7yz  | [  {  "event": "lunch",   "start": "109"},  {  "event": "movie",  "start": "97" } ]   |
| bx4y  | [  {  "event": "dinner",   "start": "78"},  {  "event": "sleep",  "start": "25" } ]   |
```

I want to flatten the JSON array elements so that my result output is:

```
| id    | name.event | name.start |
|-------|------------|------------|
| a1xy  | sports     | 100        |
| a1xy  | lunch      | 121        |
| a7yz  | lunch      | 109        |
| a7yz  | movie      | 97         |
| bx4y  | dinner     | 78         |
| bx4y  | sleep      | 25         |
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: can you provide the source of the data, so it becomes easy to recreate this

Answer (score 1):

You can use python json library to parse JSON with pandas apply function and create a list which you can later convert to dataframe using pandas concat function then change the index of that dataframe.

```
import json
ll = df.name.apply(lambda row: pd.DataFrame(json.loads(row))).tolist()
new_df = pd.concat(ll)
new_df.index = pd.Series(new_df.index).shift(-1).fillna(0).cumsum()
```

new_df

```
      event start
1.0  sports   100
1.0   lunch   121
2.0   lunch   109
2.0   movie    97
3.0  dinner    78
3.0   sleep    25
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply(pd.DataFrame)`

```
k= df.name.apply(pd.DataFrame).tolist()

final_df = pd.concat(k)
final_df.index = pd.Series(final_df.index).shift(-1).fillna(0).cumsum()

final_df
    event start
1  sports   100
1   lunch   121
2   lunch   109
2   movie    97
3  dinner    78
3   sleep    25
```

Comment: The values in the input dataframe column id will not to be 1,2,3; it will be varchar such as a1xy, a7yz,bx4y. can the code be modified to reflect this?

Comment: I don't get using the 'name' variable in 'df.name.aply..'. I'm getting an AttributeError..

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @Chiel In this specific example, `name` was the name of the column. You should change this for the actual name of your column. For example, if your column name is `name`, then `df['name']` or `df.name` should work fine: but if your column name is `age` or `sales`, then you should use `df['age']` (or `df.age`) and `df['sales']` (or `df.sales`)